# swift properties empty setters and getters

Tags: swift, properties, getter-setter

I'm a beginner in Ios development so please forgive me if this sounds like a silly question. I often see properties declaration like this:

```
var desiredAccuracy: CLLocationAccuracy { get set }
```

so what does `{ get set }` mean? Is it an empty getter and setter for a variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how a property requirement is declared in a protocol:

> Property requirements are always declared as variable properties, prefixed with the var keyword. Gettable and settable properties are indicated by writing { get set } after their type declaration, and gettable properties are indicated by writing { get }.

[Apple Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)

Answer (score 1):

You declared that the variable will have setter and getter both in protocol

```
protocol Abstract  {
  var desiredAccuracy: Int { get set }
}

//so here  you can implement the abstract with struct or class.
struct  Concrete : Abstract {
  var desiredAccuracy: Int
}

var concrete =  Concrete(desiredAccuracy: 10)
print(concrete.desiredAccuracy)   <--  this is getter 
concrete.desiredAccuracy = 20     <--  this is setter
print(concrete.desiredAccuracy)   <--  this is getter
```